# RabbitMQ pika. How to fix StreamLostError

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm using pika python library for interact with RabbitMQ message broker.

To create a connection, I use:

```
def get_connection():
    credential = pika.PlainCredentials(LOGIN, PASS)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(
        HOST, 
        5672, 
        '/', 
        credential, 
        heartbeat=0,
        blocked_connection_timeout=0
    )
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    return connection
```

Further:

```
channel = get_connection().channel()
channel.basic_consume(queue='test', on_message_callback=run)
channel.start_consuming()
```

`run` function performs long calculations (~30 minutes) and after that I call `ch.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)`, but I get the error:
`StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')`

I can't figure out what I need to do to avoid this error. I changed the values of the heartbeats parameters, but it didn't help